# WordPress URL Modification

Tags: wordpress

I have a WordPress page at

```
http://www.mysiteurl.com/pagename/
```

and I want any URL of the form

```
http://www.mysiteurl.com/pagename/{any string here}
```

to redirect or display my original page: http://www.mysiteurl.com/pagename/. How do I go about doing this?

Comment: What do you mean by "original page"? Do you mean you want it to go to `http://www.mysiteurl.com/pagename/` (your wordpress homepage)?

Comment: Yes that is what I would like.

Comment: I checked the edit history and saw that you asked if there are plugins. I found these two through Google which should do what you want: https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/, https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-301-redirects/

Comment: And if you would prefer to do it programmatically, see the first answer on this page: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/181153/redirect-page-url-to-home-url-without-using-a-plugin. You just need to use `wp_redirect` to do the redirect in your `functions.php` file. Also, you first have to create a page and name the url the string that you want to redirect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like what Kodos Johnson suggested, the function should be something like this:

```
function redirect_to_page() {
  //get parsed uri separated by '/'
  $a_uri = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);   
  //check if the page is the page you want to redirect   
  if( $a_uri[1] === 'pagename' ) {
    //redirect to siteurl/pagename    
    wp_redirect( home_url('pagename'));
    exit();
  }
}

add_action('template_redirect', 'redirect_to_page');
```

Hope this helps!